# < was unexpected at this time. from curl command line when posting input data as an xml to rest service

Tags: windows, json, wcf, rest, curl

when i post a raw string as an input to JSON REST Service call it is executing ex:

```
curl -d "{\"input1\": \"as\", \"input2\": \"ad\"}"  -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost/rtygies/Service1.svc/rest/receivedata1
```

But when i am posting as an xml as input it is giveng error as below:

```
curl -d "{\"input1\": \"<xml></xml>\", \"input2\": \"<xml></xml>\"}"  -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost/rtygies/Service1.svc/rest/receivedata1
```

***Error: < was unexpected at this time***

I am using curl in windows.

can any one say how to post xml as a string input to Rest service in JSON format from curl

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I don't know what is the case,
but I got an error said `< is unexpected this time`
when I tried the following command (on windows):

```
curl -u admin:password -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<namespace><prefix>newWorkspace</prefix><uri>http://geoserver.org</uri></namespace>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces
```

Then I changed the single quote into double quotes and it worked.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, saved me a lot of frustration!

Answer (score 3):

I had no luck with double-quotes, however escaping < and > with ^ worked for me.

So your curl becomes..

```
curl -d "{\"input1\": \"^<xml^>^</xml^>\", \"input2\": \"^<xml^>^</xml^>\"}"  -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost/rtygies/Service1.svc/rest/receivedata1
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirection symbols can be escaped by "

Try using

```
curl -d "{\"input1\": \""<xml></xml>"\", \"input2\": \""<xml></xml>"\"}"  -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost/rtygies/Service1.svc/rest/receivedata1
```